# Is this the relative non-restrictive clause?

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

I don't think that this the relative non-restrictive clause, but why is there the comma before `which`?

> Hobby drones appear in all shapes and sizes, which sometimes makes the
>   process of finding the right drone for your needs difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative clause is not restrictive, but it is not a "non-restrictive relative" in the sense that term is ordinarily used. The comma (or in speech the comma intonation) marks the clause as a *supplement* to the main clause: the antecedent of *which* is not any nominal within the clause but the main clause itself. You could paraphrase:

> Hobby drones appear in all shapes and sizes; that fact sometimes makes the process of finding the right drone for your needs difficult.